# How can I retrieve a index of text inside json

Tags: javascript, json

I need to retrieved a index inside a JSON data. 
My query -> I want to get the position of the URL who contains the text "eisf" inside all the URL's.

I tried the function findIndex, but not working...

```
[{
        "title": "CAP Pâtissier à La Ciotat - GRETA Marseille Méditerranée - Académie ...",
        "url": "https://www.gretanet.com/formation-cap-patissier+la-ciotat+1007.html",
        "displayedUrl": "https://www.gretanet.com/formation-cap-patissier+la-ciotat+1007.html",
        "description": "Formation CAP Pâtissier à La Ciotat - GRETA Marseille Méditerranée - Académie d'Aix-Marseille.",
        "siteLinks": []
    },
    {
        "title": "Les sujets du CAP pâtissier - EISF",
        "url": "https://www.eisf.fr/sujets-examen-cap-patisserie/",
        "displayedUrl": "https://www.eisf.fr/sujets-examen-cap-patisserie/",
        "description": "8 déc. 2018 - Vous voulez vous entrainer à l'examen du CAP Pâtissier ? Retrouver les annales des années précédentes. Sujets CAP Pâtissier 2018.",
        "siteLinks": []
    }]
```

Comment: `findIndex()` should work fine. Show us what you tried that didn't work. The objective here is to help you with *your code* ...not to write it all for you

Comment: Yep sure! 

`json.findIndex(result=> result.url.includes("eisf"));`

Comment: Ok...so what is wrong? What is expected results?

Comment: I get -1, I shoud get 1

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/vg7dtqbp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the array using `forEach` and check if url have that text using `indexOf`. It if is greater that -1 then push it to the `indexArr`

```js
let data = [{
    "title": "CAP Pâtissier à La Ciotat - GRETA Marseille Méditerranée - Académie ...",
    "url": "https://www.gretanet.com/formation-cap-patissier+la-ciotat+1007.html",
    "displayedUrl": "https://www.gretanet.com/formation-cap-patissier+la-ciotat+1007.html",
    "description": "Formation CAP Pâtissier à La Ciotat - GRETA Marseille Méditerranée - Académie d'Aix-Marseille.",
    "siteLinks": []
  },
  {
    "title": "Les sujets du CAP pâtissier - EISF",
    "url": "https://www.eisf.fr/sujets-examen-cap-patisserie/",
    "displayedUrl": "https://www.eisf.fr/sujets-examen-cap-patisserie/",
    "description": "8 déc. 2018 - Vous voulez vous entrainer à l'examen du CAP Pâtissier ? Retrouver les annales des années précédentes. Sujets CAP Pâtissier 2018.",
    "siteLinks": []
  }
];

let indexArr = [];
data.forEach(function(item, index) {
  if (item.url.indexOf('eisf') !== -1) {
    indexArr.push(index);
  }
});

console.log(indexArr)
```